# How to check if params present in scope rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

```
scope :created_after, ->(start_time,end_time) { where("start_time > ? and end_time <?", start_time,end_time) }
```

I want to add if condition if start time present then only `start_time` query run if `end_time` then its query run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `created_between` is better name for what you want to do with your `created_after` scope.

You can create two helper scopes to filter results using `start_time` and `end_time` column.

```
scope :created_after, ->(start_time) do
  where("start_time > ?", start_time)
end

scope :created_before, ->(end_time) do
  where("end_time < ?", end_time)
end
```

Then you can combine them in a way you wanted:

```
scope :created_between, ->(start_time, end_time) do
  query = self.all
  query = query.created_after(start_time) if start_time
  query = query.created_before(end_time)  if end_time
  query
end
```

If you execute query giving `nil` for any scope argument it will ignore them. For example: `created_between(nil, nil)` will result in no additional query.

Answer (score 2):

You can just chain it in the condition

```
scope :created_after, ->(start_time, end_time) { start_time && end_time && where("start_time > ? and end_time <?", start_time, end_time) }
```

This will add the where condition only if `start_time` and `end_time` is present